# How do I validate an annotation at compile time?

Tags: java, annotations

I have an annotation defined:

```
public @interface AdminMapping {
    public final static int USER = 100;
    public final static int COMPANY = 10;
    public final static int ADMIN = 0;

    int adminLevel() default AdminMapping.USER;
    String displayName();
    String category() default "";
    String hasPermission() default "";
    String parentCategory() default "";
}
```

I want to make it so you can't have a parentCategory unless you have a category....

```
    @AdminMapping(category="Company", displayName="FOO", adminLevel=AdminMapping.USER)
public static final String MONKEY = "chimp";


    @AdminMapping(parentCategory="Company", displayName="BAR", adminLevel=AdminMapping.USER) //NOT VALID Parent without Category
public static final String HORSE = "zebra";
```

while I'm at it I'd also like it if I could make it so the category doesn't equal the parentCategory.

I know how to use ConstraintValidator to validate MONKEY and HORSE but I want to validate the actual AdminMapping entries.  Can this be done at compile time?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I haven't tried this to confirm you can do everything you want, but I would suggest looking at writing your own PMD rule to do the checks.

Comment: @matthelliwell an answer with some part of an example below would probably help me a lot and result in acceptance :)

Comment: may i know the solution @kasdega

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/). PMD is a tool that parses your source code and lets you check that it meets certain rules. It comes with lots of built in rules but you can write your own so you can write a rule to check your annotations are defined how you want.

See [this page](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.5/howtowritearule.html) for an explanation of writing your own rules.

For example, it is easy to write a rule that checks whether an annotation has both parentCategory and category defined.

First declare the custom rule in a rules xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="My custom rules"
     xmlns="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0 http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset_2_0_0.xsd">
<rule name="NoParent"
      message="No parent category without category"
      class="com.test.CategoryRule">
    <description>
        No parent category without category
    </description>

</rule>
```

Then define a Java class that will do the actual enforcement.

```
public class CategoryRule extends AbstractJavaRule {
public Object visit(ASTMemberValuePairs node, Object data) {

    boolean hasCategory = false;
    boolean hasParentCategory = false;

    for ( int i = 0; i < node.jjtGetNumChildren(); ++i ) {
        if ( node.jjtGetChild(i).getImage().equals("category") ) {
            hasCategory = true;
        } else if ( node.jjtGetChild(i).getImage().equals("parentCategory") ) {
            hasParentCategory = true;
        }
    }

    if ( hasCategory && !hasParentCategory ) {
        addViolation(data, node);
    }

    return data;
}
```

}

Obviously you'd need to write the code to be a bit more robust in reality, check the annotation type, but hopefully that enough to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get a reference to the annotation and check its attributes

```
AdminMapping mapping = ...; // depends on what your annotation is annotating

if (mapping.category().isEmpty()) {
    if (!mapping.parentCategory().isEmpty()) {
        // we got a beef
    }
}
```

Comment: @kasdega Not without writing your own compiler. You can maybe implement some code-checker plugin for an IDE.